# Defining methods outside of a class's scope via function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

**Preface**

I am trying to create an event system. An event will do nothing by default. If an object needs to opt into the event system, then all that is required is that the programmer defines a callable function for the listener.

In theory, this sounds great, but in reality I am not sure if it is possible to implement this sort of thing within C++. Here is an example of what I imagine the code to look like.

---

**Outline**

```
#include <iostream>

enum Color{ red, green, blue };

class Event {
public:
    // Would be called within the context of a loop.
    // Each time we go through the loop, we would have different input.
    void listen(const Color& color) {
        // If the callable is defined, then call it.
        if(callable) callable(color);
    }

    // We would pass in function to be called within listen()
    void defineAction(void(*function)(const Color &color)) {
        callable = function;
    }
private:
    void (*callable)(const Color& color) = nullptr;
};

class Greeter: public Event {
    void greet() { std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Greeter greeter;

    // This doesn't work for two reasons. We cannot define a function here,
    // and scoping rules wont allow for an implicit this->greet().
    // Ideally, I would like to do this inline with a lambda
    /*void greetIfRed(const Color& color) {
        if(color == red)
            // call greet().
    }
    greeter.defineAction(&greetIfRed);
    */
}
```

---

**Expanding on this idea**

Basically, the Event class will receive something that will be changing each time we go through the event loop. I chose color for this example, but it could be mouse coordinates, an integer, or something else. That type will need to be strictly defined before hand.

In my design, I don't want it to matter what classes we have within the event loop. We could have a greeter, a player, or something that just says farewell. I imagine that the event loop would look something like this. (psuedocode)

```
while(event) {
    greeter.listen(event)
    player.listen(event)
    text.listen(event)  // e.g.,the text could change color if the mouse is over it,
}
```

---

**The Question**

Is it possible to define a method outside a class's scope via a function pointer that utilizes said class's methods? This would need to work for a sub class. The class `Greet` and the function `greetIfRed` capture  the functionality that I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I think you are maybe looking for [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and/or [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) ..? Also,  [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) ,  No? Also; event classes are often `union`s.

Comment: This sounds like something you would do by deriving a class from `Event` that would implement its own `listen()` function. In other words, `listen` would be `virtual`. Rather than deciding to call `callable()` based on whether a function pointer is set, you can make the decision automatically by calling the correct class's `listen()` function... and of course, by any custom logic applicable to that class.

Comment: You will need to pass a reference to `greeter` into that function. Doing it C-style will involve adding `void *` and casting greeter to / from it. More type-safe way would be to define a dedicated class.

Comment: Thanks to you all. Are any of you able to get a working example?

Comment: Is there a reason why `Greeter::greet()` is private? Or could it be public?

Comment: @ChrisDrew No, reason. The callable could be protected as well. It would be necessary to make it protected to make listen a virtual function.

Comment: You can have a pointer to class member function. Combined with a class instance, it can call an arbitrary member function. It can sub-class. It can also be NULL (meaning it does not point to any member function). You can also have pointer to class member data. This can also be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

So, I experimented with many suggestions, and I managed to create a working example without many changes. I compiled this with C++14.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

enum Color{ red, green, blue };

class Event {
public:
    void listen(const Color& color) {
        if(callable) callable(color);
    }

    void defineAction( std::function<void(const Color& color)> function) {
        callable = function;
    }

protected:
    std::function<void(const Color& color)> callable = nullptr;
};

class Greeter: public Event {
public:
    void greet() { std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Greeter greeter;

    greeter.defineAction([&greeter](const Color& color){
        if(color == red)
            greeter.greet();
    });
    greeter.listen(red);
    greeter.listen(green);
}
```

Comment: Only problem I see with this code is that `addActionListener` is a Java method name and therefore strongly suggests the Java behavior of maintaining a list of callbacks.  This code doesn't maintain a list, the function's behavior would be better expressed by `replace_listener` or `set_listener`.

Comment: Hmm, I'll change it. Thanks.